# <span _ngcontent-c3="" xpath="1"> 5 </span

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am not able to get the dynamic text " 5 " from the code. When I use gettext() getting 0 ,instead of 5

`<span _ngcontent-c3="" xpath="1">5</span>`

I tried xpath = `"//div[4]//div[1]//div[2]//div[1]//p[3]//span[2]"`

5

getting "0" instead of "5"

[image]

Comment: Update the question with text based relevant HTML, code trials and error observed (if any)

Comment: Please add the proper question

Answer (score 0):

Most probably your XPath expression matches more than one element, try calling [findElements()](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#findElements-org.openqa.selenium.By-) instead of [findElement()](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#findElement-org.openqa.selenium.By-) and check the size of the returned [List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html)

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[4]//div[1]//div[2]//div[1]//p[3]//span[2]"));
System.out.println("Found " + elements.size() + " matching elements");
```

If you will have result > 1 - you will need to amend your expression. If you have 1 - you will still have to amend your expression to match correct element.

From what I can see so far you can stick to this `xpath` [attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_attributes.asp) value, something like:

```
//span[@xpath='1']
```

References:

- [XPath Syntax](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp)
- [XPath Axes](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_axes.asp)
- [XPath Operators & Functions](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=40044727)

Answer (score 0):

Got it, I need to wait for some time to get the text from the application by default or when page loads value will be "0"

After adding `thread.sleep(2000);` before `gettext();` I am getting the dynamic value.

Answer (score 0):

I see and I assume "Bikes In Use" as a static. So we can use ancestor xpath
like

```
span[text() = 'Bikes In Use']/ancestor::p
```

You can correct it if something is missing in the xpath